# Xmobar DiskU not get the root partition information in Slackware 15

Tags: haskell, xmonad, slackware, xmobar

I trying to show the root partition usage in the Xmobar (with XMonad), but not working!! Without any verbose or error message.
I don't know if the problem is the way as the Slackware loading the root partition or its way of the xmobar working.
Explaining the context:
The disk have three partitions: `"swap", "/" and "/home"`

```
/dev/sda1 is the /
/dev/sda2 is the swap
/dev/sda3 is the /home
```

in the Slackware, the system creates a virtual mount point to `"/dev/sda1"`  calling it the `"/dev/root"` with mount point to `"/"`

In the Xmobar (`.xmobarrc` file), any of the options below not work:

```
- Run DiskU [ ( "/", "<size>" ) ] [] 20
- Run DiskU [ ( "root", "<size>" ) ] [] 20
- Run DiskU [ ( "/dev/root", "<size>" ) ] [] 20
- Run DiskU [ ( "sda1", "<size>" ) ] [] 20
- Run DiskU [ ( "/dev/sda1", "<size>" ) ] [] 20
```

and calling

```
- Run DiskU [ ( "/", "<size>" ), ("/home", "<size>") ] [] 20
```

where `"/home"` is the `"/dev/sda3"` partition, works fine to get the information about `"/home"`

Reading Xmobar sources, i see that the list of the available partition is read from `"/etc/mtab"`. In my case, the `"/etc/mtab"` have de list of partitions below:

```
/dev/root / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
...
/dev/sda3 /home ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

but i don't get the DiskU function works...

Any idea is welcome to solve this problem...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution:

Slackware set the mount point of `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/root` automatically in `/etc/mtab`, but `/dev/root` is a virtual device and not exists in `/dev` folder.
Xmobar try to access the device `/dev/root` and not found it.

The most simple solution is creation of a symbolic link to `/dev/root` on system startup.
In this case, in Slackware, edit the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` and add:

```
ln -s /dev/sda1 /dev/root
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

With a `mount` table containing

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
# ...
/dev/sda3 /home ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

an `xmobar` configuration along these lines should actually work:

```hs
Config
  { -- ...
  , template = "... %disku% ..."
  -- ...
  , commands =
    [ -- ...
    , Run DiskU
      [ ( "/",     "Root: <usedp> (<used>/<size>)")
      , ( "/home", "Home: <usedp> (<used>/<size>)")
      ]
      [] 20
    -- ...
    ]
  -- ...
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!! But this solution not working... The problem is that the Slackware changes `/etc/fstab` mount point of `/dev/sda1` to `/dev/root` in normal mounting and in the bind mounting automatically.
Yet that i use bind mode of `"/"` to `"/mnt/hd"` in `"/etc/fstab"`, the device in the file `"/etc/mtab"` stay `"/dev/root"` in this case.

It's looks a slackware security policy...